# Handling checkbox selected values in parent window in android

Tags: android

I have a button in my parent window, which on selected will open a child window with check boxes and a button, after i completed my selection and when button is clicked, the values selected should be displayed in parent window above the parent window button. Can anyone give a code sample for this. It will be of great help to me .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you want to show selected value in simple textview??let me clear..

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dialog`. Following link will help you.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog